# I can`t authorize with gspread on Python 3

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I have a simple script with creating googlesheet on Python 3.6 like:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

mail = 'my_mail@gmail.com'
secret_file = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\my_file.json"

SCOPES = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(secret_file, SCOPES)

gss_client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
gss = gss_client.open('test-doc')
worksheet = gss.sheet1
```

But when I run it, I have a type-error:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> >     "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/fjhdshfjs.py", line 11, in
> >      ...
> >     "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\base64.py",
> >     line 58, in b64encode
> >         encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False) TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Early, this trouble could be resolved with encoding:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'].encode(), scope)
```

But now, it doesn`t work after *moving SignedJwtAssertionCredentials onto oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials*

Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: you can use the credential file you download from Google directly in `gspread.authorize("credentials.json")`

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you are after is closer to this

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Sheets API
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                            range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts)

Comment: I`ve written code again:

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
but it still not working with the same error. Where is mistake?

Comment: sounds like something is wrong with your credentials file have you tried following the documentation link?

Comment: Yes, I created service account and get credential files in JSON. It looks like this:
{
  "type": "service_acc",
  "project_id": docs",
  "private_key_id": sdadasd221312312
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN -END PRIVATE KEY",
  "client_email": "sdsdsdsds@.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": 1223213213211
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/"
}